# Is AJAX Writable in both PHP and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I know this is probably a beginner question, but I've read about what AJAX "is" and a little about how it works, and I have a little background in both PHP and JavaScript.  So I found a few HelloWorlds for AJAX but one was written in PHP:

```
<?php
require_once('../qcubed.inc.php');

// Define the Qform with all our Qcontrols
class ExamplesForm extends QForm {
  // Local declarations of our Qcontrols
  protected $lblMessage;
  protected $btnButton;

  // Initialize our Controls during the Form Creation process
  protected function Form_Create() {
      // Define the Label
      $this->lblMessage = new QLabel($this);
      $this->lblMessage->Text = 'Click the button to change my message.';

      // Definte the Button
      $this->btnButton = new QButton($this);
      $this->btnButton->Text = 'Click Me!';

      // Add a Click event handler to the button -- the action to run is an AjaxAction.
      // The AjaxAction names a PHP method (which will be run asynchronously) called "btnButton_Click"
      $this->btnButton->AddAction(new QClickEvent(), new QAjaxAction('btnButton_Click'));
  }
  // The "btnButton_Click" Event handler
  protected function btnButton_Click($strFormId, $strControlId, $strParameter) {
      $this->lblMessage->Text = 'Hello, world!';
  }
}
// Run the Form we have defined
ExamplesForm::Run('ExamplesForm');
?>
```

So I'm confused... this code block doesn't look much like PHP to me, it actually kind of looks like JAVA... Is this based on a library that implements AJAX using PHP code?  When companies say they're looking for "AJAX developers", is the PHP implementation common/acceptable, or is the standard typically the JavaScript implementation?

Comment: Looks exactly like PHP to me ? And Ajax is Asynchronous Javascript And XML, so it's not something you can write in PHP, but you can however write a serverside script that answers the ajax call from Javascript in PHP.

Comment: Yeah, it looks exactly like PHP to me, except for that the page doesn't need to reload in order to change the page...  as far as I know, PHP has to either POST or GET data to itself & reload the page to change the content, but this works like JavaScript where it's front-side.

Answer (score 2):

That is PHP code, though what you may not be seeing is that there is a massive amount of code in the backend that takes the "form" you design and translates it into html/JS and AJAX calls back to the server.  It's a nifty idea, but it does do alot of things for you, which may not be a terribly good idea for getting started with AJAX, as you'll be tying your knowledge to the framework in question.

For more info, that framework is QCubed, link: http://qcu.be/

Comment: Hmmm, ok so another stupid question then... I though that AJAX was in itself a framework/library built on top of JavaScript...  so QCubed is a framework built on top of a framework?  The reason I got pulled into this particular example is that most of the HelloWorld examples I found for AJAX were 50 lines of code & I couldn't understand any of it... this was the only one I felt I could read & understand, but I guess technically speaking, this is no more writing "ajax code" then c++ is writing "asembly code".  Thanks again!

Comment: AJAX is just a name given to a technique used in javascript to get data from a server without reloading the page. It's not a framework and while X in AJAX stands for XML, we use that technique to request any kind of data (text, image...). You can make AJAX requests in pure javascript (all existing web browsers support it) or use a library to handle the specifics. You can learn more here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ajax/